# Adding an image onto another image Javascript (for a close button)

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am looking for a simple way to add a close icon image to another image in Javascript. I am trying to position an icon in the top right corner of the an image.

Code So Far:

```
function drawImages(imagevalue){

    var array = localStorage.getItem('images');
    array = JSON.parse(imagevalue);

    //Add HTML to screen:

    //Clear the elements that might already be in the div so they don't appear twice:
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("saveArea");
    while (theDiv.firstChild) {
    theDiv.removeChild(theDiv.firstChild);
    }


    for (var x=0; x < array.length; x++){ 
    //Create image for each value in array:

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = array[x];
    img.width = 300;
    img.height = 150;
    img.style.marginRight="10px";
    img.className = "saveImg";

            //this image needs to be placed in the top right corner of the
            //image named img. 
    var close = document.createElement("close");
    close.src="close.png";


    document.getElementById("saveArea").appendChild(img);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't work?  Something like `position:relative;right:0;top:0;`

Comment: but how would you put the close image inside the other img in js. when the page loads these iamges aren't there yet.

Comment: you would actually put both of them into a container div.